# User Messaging with RoR and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, private-messaging

i searched the web now several hours but get no clear answer.

I have a Rails-App (Ruby 1.9.3/Rails 3.2.2/MongoDB) which uses Devise as User-Authorization.

Now i'd like to have a simple messaging function between users: 1 to 1 and 1 to n.

Are there any gems that fulfill this need and support Mongo or are there any tutorials or best practices for this?

Maybe relevant too: In the next step i plan to make the messages available in an iOS and Android App (both native) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need implement it. A gem to do that is too specific and need a lot of update to be generic.

I think anyone do that.

Sending message to iOS and Android is completly different so you can't have gem to do that easily. Code it.